# Need to validate approach: Spring Integration + AMQP + Async

Tags: asynchronous, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I've been recently investigating about Spring Integration and AMQP (RabbitMQ), as I need to communicate two applications (middleware and backend) with async approach, so that the middleware doesn't block when receiving client calls.

I first followed the simpler approach of implementing this in a synchronous, this meaning that I have a gateway interface and an outbound gateway (with requiresReply=true) on the middleware, and then an inbound gateway and a service activator on the backend. This initial approach works well (I've used Spring Integration XML config).

Now I need clarification on the approach to follow to make this work in an async way.

By looking at the RabbitMQ Tutorial 6, it's better to work with a callback queue and a correlationId, and per what I understood, this would be similar to calling Spring RabbitTemplate's convertAndSend() and then receive(), instead of convertSendAndReceive() (which would block until response is received).

I've checked the Spring Integration docs, where I need to replace the gateway interface on the middleware for it to return Future or ListenableFuture.

[Async Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/whats-new.html#4.1-async-gateway)

Once that's done, I also looked at the documentation for the [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html), where it says that it can work together with the RabbitTemplate to manage the correlationID and replyTo message attributes.

My questions are:

1. In order to make this work with an async approach, should I keep working with outbound/inbound gateways, instead of outbound/inbound message converters?
2. In case of following the outbound/inbound message converters approach (which sounds to me similar to what the RabbitMQ tutorial shows), how do I associate the Future on the gateway interface with the result coming back from with inbound channel adapter?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already checked this [another entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469486/spring-integration-with-rabbit-amqp-for-client-sends-message-server-receives) which points me to the RabbitTemplate docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest you don't provide an original business requirement. It might be a fact that there is really no reason to get deal with this `async` handsoff, because you have a `@Gateway` as an entry point which is thread-free and even if it is blocked to wait for the reply it doesn't impact other threads which may perform similar `sendAndReceive` operation. In most cases it is really just enough to do everything within the same requestor thread and don't loose performance with shifting to the shared `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Right, the `Future` allows you to free a caller a bit to be ready to accept new requests within the same thread.

Since it is a `MessagingGateway` and you want to have a reply anyway, there is a hook associated with the request - `TemporaryReplyChannel` header. That's why that `<outbound-gateway>` works properly: it place its blocking reply to that channel for the gateway's `return` (or for `FutureTask#set()`).

I'd say that we can achieve the same `TemporaryReplyChannel` gain with that your async reply requirement.

1. You should use `inbound`/`outbound` channel adapter pair.
2. Before send the message to the `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` you should do this `<header-channels-to-string>` for the `<header-enricher>`.
3. The server side maybe the same - `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway>`
4. You should use **fixed** `replyQueue` as a header for those message to send through the `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`
5. the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` should be configured for that **fixed** `replyQueue`.
6. Both `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` on client side and `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway>` must be configured for the `mapped-request-headers="*"` to allow to propagate that `reply-channel` header to the server and vise versa.
7. The `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` on the client side will just send the reply to the `reply-channel` as it is for the `<int-amqp:outbound-gateway>`
8. You may need to take care about the `correlationId` manually, since `<int-amqp:inbound-gateway>` may require that to produce a reply properly.

Well, something like that...

HTH

Feel free to ask more questions. Or correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks Artem for your response. I agree that probably requirements don't need the async approach (I'm on the proof of concept now, and I'd like to know whether I can use the async approach if needed). All in all, my question is whether I should keep the outbound-gateway on the producer (which I wonder blocks until the response is received), or should I replace it by separate outbound-channel-adapter + inbound-channel-adapter? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, do you wait for anything else from me?

Comment: No, thanks Artem. I'm just going with the approach of using the outbound-gateway, instead of replacing it by outbound / inbound channel-adapters. Thanks, Franco.

Comment: Well, the good tone in that case to accept answer to close the topic